# Learn jQuery and AJAX for Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need a good resource to get started with AJAX on Rails, where everything is explained from ground-up, in detail. Please suggest.

Comment: learn coffeescript http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script

Comment: I don't advice learning coffeescript until you've learnt how to code javascript fully. Also it's sort of unrelated, as he's asking how to learn to use AJAX & RoR concurrently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read this blogpost on [Unobtrusive JavaScript in Rails 3](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) as a good starting point. However, I personally prefer writing my own Javascript and AJAX methods instead of relying on Rails helpers to do it for me, since that gives me finer control over what I intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not as simple as that, first you should learn Ruby, then learn AJAX + jQuery, then use them concurrently. However, to contradict everything I just said, here is a guide for RoR and AJAX:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Ruby-on-Rails/Ruby-on-Rails-and-AJAX/

Sorry I can't help more, I have no experience in RoR. Using AJAX isn't specific to RoR though, so that is why there isn't many resources regarding both RoR and AJAX. Maybe find tutorials on using AJAX and PHP, or AJAX and ASP.NET, the AJAX will be fundamentally the same as it is not language specific, and then write your own code in RoR. This may actually be highly beneficial, as you know what you want the output to be, but you are writing the code from scratch (instead of copy + paste) with just fundamental guidance.

Or just read that link I posted ;)

Comment: You posted an article from 2007. Rails has seen so much change in things since then. Articles from late 2010 are even sometimes irrelevant now. Things like ```:remote => true``` wouldn't even begin to be discussed in this article.

Comment: I am very much familiar with Ruby, Rails and jQuery. What i need is a good book I guess, to understand the concepts of integrating AJAX, with any platform. I guess I am going to buy and read the book Ajax On Rails, and then see where I go. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Caley Woods.. so I assume the fundamentals of RoR aren't even the same? Like I said I know nothing about RoR at all... surely that means RoR that was wrote 4 years ago won't work any more? rookieRailer, like Gaurav said down below, try using custom AJAX.. it will also make you a better coder in the long run.

Comment: The way ajax is handled in rails has gone through several recent changes. Your code may still work on the old version of rails but you wouldn't be able to upgrade it to 3.0.9 or 3.1 and have it work, no.